# Pipe Java to Grep: Why not working?

Tags: java, bash, grep, pipe

I am trying to run this dreadfully simple command in Bash

```
java -cp nasa-top-secret.jar gov.nasa.RocketToMoon | grep -v codehaus
```

but grep is not working (it does not filter out my string). How can I filter my `java` output using `grep`?

Comment: What is the result of ``java -cp nasa-top-secret.jar gov.nasa.RocketToMoon``?

Comment: @nanda, it's causing an OutOfMemoryException :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The output could be on STDERR, Try this instead:

```
java -cp nasa-top-secret.jar gov.nasa.RocketToMoon 2>&1 | grep -v codehaus
```

Answer (score 3):

possible scenario

1. you actually have all the lines with
   "codehaus", so grep -v  gives you
   nothing. I assume you know what `-v`
   stands for.
2. your java program did not print
   anything to stdout. check your
   source and make sure your program spits out to stdout. Otherwise, check if its stderr that your program is spitting out.

possible troubleshooting step:

1. remove the pipe to grep, run only the java program and make
   sure your program has output.
2. put `2>&1` at the end of the command
   and try again with grep